# MySQL event schedule from another table's dates

Tags: mysql, date, events

Is it possible to run MySQL event based on dates stored in table?

For example if I have table like

```
| id | date       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 2016-05-20 |
| 2  | 2016-05-25 |
| 3  | 2016-06-15 |
...
```

can I run event automatically at 2016-05-20, 2016-05-25 and 2016-06-15?

Answer (score 1):

Your daily event should check that table and run its code if today's date is in it !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to run event automatically at 2016-05-20, 2016-05-25 and 2016-06-15 dates by using `cron-job`.

You can run daily event, check with your table date and run its code.
Suppose you want to automatically run your script file at some dates, you need to set `cron-job` using php. Ref [How to create cron job using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)